# Race condition via use of Java's ExecutorService?

Tags: java, http, concurrency

I have a class which loosely implements the [HTTP Ranged-GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233) protocol. Essentially, some code invokes this class, telling it to download a file. The below `MyClass` is responsible for downloading the file in even-sized chunks (until the last chunk, which may be variable-length), and sending it to another service. When invoked, it sets the file size based on the Content-Range instance-length from the 1st HTTP response.

The class uses an [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) with a thread pool size of 1 to control threading.

Below is the relevant implementation, with some hand-waving over the functions handling the GETs and PUTs.

```
class MyClass implements Runnable {
    private long start;
    private long chunkSize;
    private int chunkNumber;
    private int fileSize = 0;

    private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 3;

    public static final ExecutorService ES = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public MyClass(long start, long chunkSize, int chunkNumber) {
        this.start = start;
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
        this.chunkNumber = chunkNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RETRIES; i++) {

            long end = start + chunkSize - 1; // inclusive so subtract 1

            // doHttpGet() is a private instance function...
            // if fileSize == 0 (i.e. first chunk downloaded), this will set the fileSize
            doHttpGet(start, end);

            // doHttpPost() is a private instance function
            // it builds the POST from the GET message, which I'm not bothering to show here
            if (!doHttpPost()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                submitNextChunk(this);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // this is the function a client uses to invoke the class
    public static void submitWork(long newStartByte, long chunkSize, int chunkNumber) {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass(newStartByte, chunkSize, chunkNumber);
        if (ES.submit(mc) == null) {
            //log error
        }
    }

    // PROBLEM AREA?!?!
    private static void submitNextChunk(MyClass mc) {
        mc.chunkNumber++;
        mc.start += mc.chunkSize;
        // LOGGER.debug("start=" + mc.start + "\n" + "fileSize=" + mc.fileSize)
        if (mc.start < mc.fileSize) {
            if (ES.submit(mc) == null) {
                //log error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is a snippet of the code which invokes `MyClass`.

```
long chunkSize = //somecalculation
DownloadAction.submitWork(0L, chunkSize, 1));
```

This code has been working fine, for a long time. However, I'm now noticing a potentially non-deterministic behavior when the file-to-download is extremely small (e.g., < 50 bytes). What appears to be happening is that the `submitNextChunk()` function does not seem to evaluate `mc.start < mc.fileSize` correctly. For example, if we set the packetSize=100K, and use a 50 byte file, then what I see -- via Wireshark -- is continuous HTTP GET requests asking for bytes 0-99999, 100000-199000, and 200000-299000, ..., etc. (The code on the other end is also slightly broken, as it continues to give us the original 50 bytes, rather than an HTTP out-of-range error code... but that another story.)

My concern was that there is a subtle race condition:

If I put some logging in `submitNextChunk()` to print out `start` and `fileSize`, then I *only* see one log statement of start=100000 and fileSize=100, and the function evaluates the less-than expression correctly to false. This makes sense, since it would be the first and only time `submitNextChunk()` would be called, and since that expression evaluates false, the function aborts.

I am concerned that this is somehow a threading issue, since *without* the debug statements, that less-than expression clearly results to `true`, which should not be occurring.

Comment: Where does your client invoke the `submitWork` method? It has private access. Because you only have only one thread to run your task, there won't be any race conditions.

Comment: Oops. That is a public function. I fixed the code snippet. It’s called from a web container. I agree that a thread condition is unlikely; however the observed behavior is indicative. I was concerned that somehow the calls through the Executor and the recursion is somehow acting  with unexpected consequences

Comment: @MattTimmermans' theory is reasonable. what does your `doHttpGet()` method return? does it block?

Comment: This part looks like it works.  I would guess that there are writes to `fileSize` or `start` that are happening in other threads and there are no memory barriers in place to make sure that `submitNextChunk` can see them all.

Comment: try adding synchronization to the method that set the `fileSize`. If they only have private access inside your `MyClass`, then it is likely the code that set the `fileSize` within the methods internally use another thread for the http request.

Comment: try declaring chunkSize, chunkNumber, and fileSize as volatile.

Comment: @lscoughlin That’s pretty much what I’ve resolved to trying at this point. I will let you know how it goes.